# React hooks check what state change caused re-render

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks, rerender

Now with hooks, I've got the component's state split into more miniature states. This seemed better until I wanted to find out what state change caused a specific re-render.

How can one easily find out what state change caused a specific re-render?

Comment: Do you refer to the `componentWillUpdate` (or `componentDidUpdate`) style checks where you have current and future (or previous) state?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? There might be some other way of going about it.

Comment: @Tholle for a moment I thought I'm chatting with Eckhart Tolle and became so damn present :D Anyway, I don't think I can explain it better, I want to know what state change caused a specific re-render. E.g. you have setVar1, setVar2, setVar3, all derived from useState, and I want to know which one of these caused the re-render

Comment: Which purpose do you want to know this for? Debugging? State management?

Comment: @estus currently for debugging but there could be other use cases

Comment: The big shift in thinking from class components to function components with hooks is that instead of checking what changed in e.g. `componentDidUpdate`, you use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects) with the dependencies given in an array as second argument so that the effect runs automatically when the dependencies change. You could create a `useEffect` for each piece of state you have.

Answer (score 3):

If state updates need to be tracked for state management like accessing previous state values, this should be handled explicitly with custom hooks that wrap `useState`.

As for debugging, React dev tools currently don't offer this functionality, although this information may be available through renderer undocumented API used in dev tools.

It's possible to add a breakpoint inside React [`dispatchAction`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.8.4/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1047) function and walk call stack up to know which state setter was called:

[image: debug useState]

Or custom hook can be used instead of `useState` to keep track of state updates:

```
const useDebuggableState = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  useMemo(() => {
    'a line to add breakpoint';
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setState];
};
```